How to put SHA256 hash in HTML input element (<input type text="text"></input>
I'm curious on how to put SHA256 hash in HTML input element. Also to mention that I'm using seperate JS function to get value which will be hashed in SHA256.
I'm using this SHA256 function:
function sha256(ascii) {
    function rightRotate(value, amount) {
        return (value>>>amount) | (value<<(32 - amount));
    };
    
    var mathPow = Math.pow;
    var maxWord = mathPow(2, 32);
    var lengthProperty = 'length'
    var i, j;
    var result = ''
  
    var words = [];
    var asciiBitLength = ascii[lengthProperty]*8;
    
    var hash = sha256.h = sha256.h || [];
    var k = sha256.k = sha256.k || [];
    var primeCounter = k[lengthProperty];
  
    var isComposite = {};
    for (var candidate = 2; primeCounter < 64; candidate++) {
        if (!isComposite[candidate]) {
            for (i = 0; i < 313; i += candidate) {
                isComposite[i] = candidate;
            }
            hash[primeCounter] = (mathPow(candidate, .5)*maxWord)|0;
            k[primeCounter++] = (mathPow(candidate, 1/3)*maxWord)|0;
        }
    }
    
    ascii += '\x80'
    while (ascii[lengthProperty]%64 - 56) ascii += '\x00' 
    for (i = 0; i < ascii[lengthProperty]; i++) {
        j = ascii.charCodeAt(i);
        if (j>>8) return; 
        words[i>>2] |= j << ((3 - i)%4)*8;
    }
    words[words[lengthProperty]] = ((asciiBitLength/maxWord)|0);
    words[words[lengthProperty]] = (asciiBitLength)
    
    for (j = 0; j < words[lengthProperty];) {
        var w = words.slice(j, j += 16); 
        var oldHash = hash;
        hash = hash.slice(0, 8);
        
        for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            var i2 = i + j;
            var w15 = w[i - 15], w2 = w[i - 2];
            var a = hash[0], e = hash[4];
            var temp1 = hash[7]
                + (rightRotate(e, 6) ^ rightRotate(e, 11) ^ rightRotate(e, 25)) // S1
                + ((e&hash[5])^((~e)&hash[6])) // ch
                + k[i]
                + (w[i] = (i < 16) ? w[i] : (
                        w[i - 16]
                        + (rightRotate(w15, 7) ^ rightRotate(w15, 18) ^ (w15>>>3)) // s0
                        + w[i - 7]
                        + (rightRotate(w2, 17) ^ rightRotate(w2, 19) ^ (w2>>>10)) // s1
                    )|0
                );
            var temp2 = (rightRotate(a, 2) ^ rightRotate(a, 13) ^ rightRotate(a, 22)) // S0
                + ((a&hash[1])^(a&hash[2])^(hash[1]&hash[2])); // maj
            
            hash = [(temp1 + temp2)|0].concat(hash);
            hash[4] = (hash[4] + temp1)|0;
        }
        
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            hash[i] = (hash[i] + oldHash[i])|0;
        }
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 3; j + 1; j--) {
            var b = (hash[i]>>(j*8))&255;
            result += ((b < 16) ? 0 : '') + b.toString(16);
        }
    }
    return result;
  };
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById('teststring').value = sha256(maketeststring(20));
    const saveHash = sha256(maketeststring(20));
    console.log(saveHash);
  });

This is my seperate JS function to get 'maketeststring' variable:
function maketeststring(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
      counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(maketeststring(20));

And this is my HTML element input code:
<input class="test_string" id="teststring" type="text" readonly></input>
I want 'maketeststring' variable to be displayed in console and to put SHA256 hash of 'maketeststring' as input value, so when I want to validate hashed and unhashed values it matches. (same 'maketeststring' value should be used to get SHA256 hash, and be displayed in debug console.) Thanks in advance!

Each call to maketeststring() makes a different string. So saveHash won't be the same as the hash in the teststring input.

you should call sha256(maketeststring(20)) just once, and put it in both places.

You should just make one random string, not two different ones.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const saveHash = sha256(maketeststring(20));
  document.getElementById('teststring').value = saveHash;
  console.log(saveHash);
});

function maketeststring(length) {
  let result = '';
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  const charactersLength = characters.length;
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter < length) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    counter += 1;
  }
  return result;
}

function sha256(ascii) {
  function rightRotate(value, amount) {
    return (value >>> amount) | (value << (32 - amount));
  };

  var mathPow = Math.pow;
  var maxWord = mathPow(2, 32);
  var lengthProperty = 'length'
  var i, j;
  var result = ''

  var words = [];
  var asciiBitLength = ascii[lengthProperty] * 8;

  var hash = sha256.h = sha256.h || [];
  var k = sha256.k = sha256.k || [];
  var primeCounter = k[lengthProperty];

  var isComposite = {};
  for (var candidate = 2; primeCounter < 64; candidate++) {
    if (!isComposite[candidate]) {
      for (i = 0; i < 313; i += candidate) {
        isComposite[i] = candidate;
      }
      hash[primeCounter] = (mathPow(candidate, .5) * maxWord) | 0;
      k[primeCounter++] = (mathPow(candidate, 1 / 3) * maxWord) | 0;
    }
  }

  ascii += '\x80'
  while (ascii[lengthProperty] % 64 - 56) ascii += '\x00'
  for (i = 0; i < ascii[lengthProperty]; i++) {
    j = ascii.charCodeAt(i);
    if (j >> 8) return;
    words[i >> 2] |= j << ((3 - i) % 4) * 8;
  }
  words[words[lengthProperty]] = ((asciiBitLength / maxWord) | 0);
  words[words[lengthProperty]] = (asciiBitLength)

  for (j = 0; j < words[lengthProperty];) {
    var w = words.slice(j, j += 16);
    var oldHash = hash;
    hash = hash.slice(0, 8);

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      var i2 = i + j;
      var w15 = w[i - 15],
        w2 = w[i - 2];
      var a = hash[0],
        e = hash[4];
      var temp1 = hash[7] +
        (rightRotate(e, 6) ^ rightRotate(e, 11) ^ rightRotate(e, 25)) // S1
        +
        ((e & hash[5]) ^ ((~e) & hash[6])) // ch
        +
        k[i] +
        (w[i] = (i < 16) ? w[i] : (
          w[i - 16] +
          (rightRotate(w15, 7) ^ rightRotate(w15, 18) ^ (w15 >>> 3)) // s0
          +
          w[i - 7] +
          (rightRotate(w2, 17) ^ rightRotate(w2, 19) ^ (w2 >>> 10)) // s1
        ) | 0);
      var temp2 = (rightRotate(a, 2) ^ rightRotate(a, 13) ^ rightRotate(a, 22)) // S0
        +
        ((a & hash[1]) ^ (a & hash[2]) ^ (hash[1] & hash[2])); // maj

      hash = [(temp1 + temp2) | 0].concat(hash);
      hash[4] = (hash[4] + temp1) | 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      hash[i] = (hash[i] + oldHash[i]) | 0;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (j = 3; j + 1; j--) {
      var b = (hash[i] >> (j * 8)) & 255;
      result += ((b < 16) ? 0 : '') + b.toString(16);
    }
  }
  return result;
};
<input class="test_string" id="teststring" type="text" readonly></input>




So you are suggesting that I need to change this in mine SHA256 JS function, and it should work?

you don't need to make any changes to the sha256() function. This is a caller of the function.

This has nothing to do with sha256() at all. The problem is that you call maketeststring() multiple times, and each time it makes a different random string. So you get different hashes.

Yeah, when I try to verify both hashed and unhashed values, it is not matching because one string is used to get hashed, and different string is used to display in console. Can you help me solving this problem, since I'm new to this?

My answer should have solved that. There's just one hashed value, and it's put in the value and the console.

It's not working for me, SHA256 hash is displayed as value in input element, and in console. But when I try to verify hashed and unhashed value, it does not matching. 'ba1858e293dff0fad09067eaa2da1d11256c40ec14701f604327d54b1cc52887' this is my SHA256 hash displayed in console, and shown as input value, and this is my 'gt5Hi9LDHntgniIY9Vim' 'maketeststring' variable result. You can verify that this 'maketeststring' hash value is not matching with mine SHA256 hash displayed as input value. This is my problem actually.

Where are you getting the unhashed value from? If you call maketeststring() again, you'll get a different unhashed value.

Maybe you should change maketeststring() so it's not random, and you get the same value each time you call it.

I want to get new 'maketeststring' result whenever I refresh my website, so automatically input value will be changed when I refresh my website as well since 'maketeststring' is string which is used to hash. Can you help me with keeping 'maketeststring' the same in one session (so same string is displayed to console and used for hash)?

It sounds like you need to save that in a global variable, and use that through the rest of the code.

Yeah, but how can I do that? To save one string only for that one session?

Do you know how to use global variables? If you want it in multiple pages in the session, use sessionStorage

Why are you hashing in the client, anyway? If this is a password, it should be hashed on the server, not the client.

Thanks for help, really appreciate it, and I'm hashing this on client on purpose, it's not password :D
